# Effective Date Employee Entered Pay Group

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the `effective date` when the employee entered the pay group. It either occurred at the hire date, the rehire date, or Transfer date, whichever is latest. I think what I want to do is create a temp table of most recent effective dates `where C1.ACTION=('XFR') AND C1.PAYGROUP=A.PAYGROUP`, when the associate is `not` in that table, give me `most recent hire date`.

- **A** is Top of Stack Employee Dta
- **B** is Top of Stack Personal Data
- **C** is entire employee record

**Most Recent Hire Date** is

```
CASE WHEN A.HIRE_DT<=A.REHIRE_DT THEN A.REHIRE_DT 
                                 ELSE A.HIRE_DT END MOST_REC_HIREDT
```

FYI I know this query is really messed up, that's why I'm asking for help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
A.EMPLID
A.FIRST_NAME||' '||A.LAST_NAME WORKERNAME,
CASE
   WHEN(Select Max(C1.EFFDT) FROM JOB C1
      WHERE (C.EMPLID=C1.EMPLID
      AND C1.ACTION=('TAF')
      AND C1.PAYGROUP=A.PAYGROUP
      AND C1.EFFDT>=(CASE WHEN A.HIRE_DT<A.REHIRE_DT THEN =A.REHIRE_DT
      ELSE A.HIRE_DT END MR_HIRE_DT)))
   WHEN A.EMPLID NOT IN JOB C1 
      THEN (CASE WHEN A.HIRE_DT<=A.REHIRE_DT 
      THEN A.REHIRE_DT 
      ELSE A.HIRE_DT END MR_HIRE_DT2)
   ELSE 'Null' END EFFDT,
A.PAYGROUP
FROM EMPLOYEES A, PERSONAL_DATA B, JOB C
WHERE
A.EMPLID=B.EMPLID
AND
B.EMPLID=C.EMPLID
AND
A.PAYGROUP=C.PAYGROUP
AND
C.EMPL_STATUS in ('A','L','P','S')
```

Comment: What would really help to provide a solution is: "sample data" from each table, then, the "expected result"

Comment: where is table `B` in that query? Can you use proper ANSI joins? that will help you build better queries

Comment: Please include sample data from each table, as well as the output you want to get as a result. Also, if you have a comma in your `FROM` clause you're most likely doing something wrong. Use a proper `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

It really is important to use ANSI join syntax as it aids (a lot) in working through the logic of how the tables relate. Here we only have 2 tables but in the example query there are 4 table aliases in use (A, B, C and C1). Additionally it helps to use table aliases that relate to the table's name such as `E` for `Employee`, `J` for `Job`.

What you are seeking is "the latest" date from table `JOB`, and an extremely useful function `row_number()` can be used for this. It is used in conjunction with an `over()` clause which contains a `partition by` (which is a little similar to group by) and an `order by`. When ordered by date descending then the row number is 1 for the most recent date (per employee due to the partition used). So, if we filter the subquery below by `is_latest = 1` we get one row per employee with the latest effective date. Note this also removes the need to use `select distinct` now.

```
SELECT
       E.EMPLID
     , (E.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || E.LAST_NAME) WORKERNAME
     , J.EFFDT PAYGROUP_EFFDT
     , E.PAYGROUP
FROM EMPLOYEES E
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  JOB.*
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLID
                                     ORDER BY EFFDT DESC) AS is_latest
            FROM JOB
            WHERE EMPL_STATUS IN ('A','L','P','S')
      ) J ON E.EMPLID=J.EMPLID AND J.is_latest = 1
```

Comment: We are modeled after peoplesoft, so we do not have row numbers, only effective dates and sequences. I am unfortunately using Oracle SQL Developer 1.5.5, and appear to have some issues doing ANSI Joins. I'm pretty familiar with the tables and where I might lose or duplicate someone by using the old format. As for the latest, I typically would do J.EFFDT= (SELECT MAX(J1.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB@EV5TEST2 J1 WHERE (J.EMPLID=J1.EMPLID AND J1.EFFDT<=SYSDATE)). In this scenario, I need to find the max effdt+sequence where J.ACTION=('TAF')  if doesn't exist, give greatest date (compare hire_dt to rehire_dt)

Answer (score 0):

I may be over-simplifying the task here, as I don't fully understand how we get to the dates in question. But well, what I am doing is:

1. get the greater of the two `hire_dt` and `rehire_dt` from the employee record
2. get the job dates for the employee
3. from these intermediate results get the first date per employee

The query:

```
select emplid, max(dt)
from
(
  select emplid, greatest(nvl(hire_dt,rehire_dt),nvl(rehire_dt,hire_dt)) as dt from employees
  union all
  select emplid, effdt as dt from job where action = 'TAF' and empl_status in ('A','L','P','S')
)
group by emplid
order by emplid;
```